# Graphs with constant edge imbalance

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, degree-sequence

The **imbalance** of an edge $(u,v) \in E(G)$ of a graph $G$ is defined as $|d(u)-d(v)|$ ($d$ being, as usual the degree). (This concept was introduced by Albertson in 1997)

I'm interested in the set of possible imbalances in a graph. In particular I am looking for examples of graphs where all edges have the same imbalance. Regular graphs trivially have this property and so does the path $P_{3}$.

> Is it true that if all edges of $G$
>   have the same imbalance, then $G$ is
>   either regular or $P_{3}$?

I have an inkling that this ought to be true by some sort of pigeonhole principle but can't think up a proof. A counterexample will be even more welcome :)

Comment: Complete bipartite graph?

Comment: More generally, any biregular graph: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biregular_graph

Comment: You need that $G$ is connected, of course. Furthermore, there are graphs with constant imbalance that are not even biregular (for example. the graph on 7 vertices with 3 vertices of degree 1 each attached to a vertex of degree 2 each attached to a unique vertex of degree 3).

Comment: And, in fact, that idea can be generalised easily to construct arbitrarily large graphs with arbitrarily large constant imbalance (take a bunch of vertices with degree 1, connect them to a bunch with degree 1+n, connect those to a bunch of 1+2n, and so on, just throwing enough vertices at each stage to make this possible).

Comment: The simplest example I can think of (included in biregular graphs) is the star graph; can be arbitrarily large, and has largest possible constant imbalance. Any edge transitive, not vertex-transitive graph gives an example.

Answer (score 2):

As Kallus and Thomas Bloom mentioned it in the comments: NO.

For example there are biregular graphs see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biregular_graph

And, (as Thomas Bloom said) that idea can be generalised easily to construct arbitrarily large graphs with arbitrarily large constant imbalance (take a bunch of vertices with degree 1, connect them to a bunch with degree 1+n, connect those to a bunch of 1+2n, and so on, just throwing enough vertices at each stage to make this possible).