# Graphs with graphic imbalance sequences

Tags: graph-theory, open-problems, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, conjectures

Let $G$ be simple undirected graph and $e=uv\in E(G)$.

The **imbalance** of the edge $e$ is the value $imb(e)=|d(u)-d(v)|$.

Let $M_{G}$ denotes the imbalance sequence (or more correctly, multiset of all edge imbalances) of $G$.

I can prove that if $T$ is a tree, then $M_{T}$ is graphic.

However, in general case it isn't true. See [A question on graphic sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140198/a-question-on-graphic-sequences) for simple counterexamples.

Based on these I came to the next

> **Imbalance Conjecture**: Suppose that for all edges $e\in E(G)$ we have $imb(e)>0$. Then $M_{G}$ is graphic.

---

**ADDED 1:** Vova Skochko, a good friend of mine, verified the conjecture for all such graphs with $\leq 9$ vertices.

**ADDED 2:** Recall that the value $Irr(G)=\sum_{e\in E(G)}imb(e)$ is called **irregularity** of $G$.

In light of Erdos-Gallai theorem the Imbalance Conjecture is equivalent to the next statement

> Suppose that for all edges $e\in E(G)$ we have $imb(e)>0$. Then for
>   all $E'\subset E(G)$ it holds
>   $$Irr(G)\leq |E'|(|E'|-1)+\sum_{e\notin E'}\left(\min\{{|E'|,imb(e)}\}+imb(e)\right).$$

I wonder does this bound on $Irr(G)$ implies other known bounds on $Irr(G)$ for such graphs?

Comment: See also the related MO question, "[Graphs with constant edge imbalance](http://mathoverflow.net/q/134513/6094)"

Comment: Sergiy, It seems like for any graph, the imbalance sequence is the degree sequence of a multigraph (repeated edges allowed). For trees this multigraph happens to be a simple graph. Perhaps the question should be to find a direct description of the associated multigraph from the original graph.

Comment: Regarding an earlier answer that was deleted, my issue with the supposed counterexample was that it did produce a degree sequence, and thus was not a counterexample as claimed.

Comment: Gjergji Zaimi, I'm interested in degrees sequences of simple graphs, not multigraphs. However, it is easy to see that $\sum M_{G}$ is always even, so the imbalance sequence of any graph is the degree sequence of some pseudograph. Oh, and I'm curious how can you prove that the imbalance sequence of a tree is graphic? Because my proof is inductional.

Comment: Checking with a computer it can be seen that your conjecture holds for *all* graphs of order up to $10.$

Comment: Jernej, no it's not! For counterexample on $9$ vertices see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140198/a-question-on-graphic-sequences

Comment: Obviously, I like this question :) Is there some special motivation or just curiosity?

Comment: I think it's both :) Because $\sum M_{G}$ is always even, $M_{G}$ is always pseudographical. However, there exist graphs for which $M_{G}$ is not multigraphical (so Gjergji Zaimi's claim is false).

Comment: @sergiy what's a counter example?

Comment: @Gjergji Zaimi: It is known that the multiset $M$ is multigraphic if and only if $\sum M$ is even and $\sum M\geq 2\max M$. Thus for every even $m\in\mathbb{N}$ one can take any $m+1$-regular graph $H$ with $\geq 4$ vertices, such that $H$ has a matching of a size $\frac{m}{2}$ (for example $H=K_{m+1,m+1}$). Then delete this matching, add new vertex $v$ and new edges from $v$ to the vertices from this matching. Then again add a new vertex $u$ and the edge $uv$ to obtain a new graph $G$. We have, that $M_{G}=\{m\}$ is not multigraphic.

Comment: I find this whole train of thought very interesting but the bound you propose is not very convenient to work with, since it apparently requires to compute stuff over all possible edge subsets. Can you find an equivalent formulation, using some other characterizaiton of graphic sequences, that produces a more accessible formula?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know any other useful characterization of graphic sequences...

Comment: Have a look here: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190150209/abstract?systemMessage=Wiley+Online+Library+will+be+unavailable+for+approximately+4+hours+between+09%3A00+EDT+and+14%3A00+EDT+on+Saturday%2C+28+September+2013+as+we+make+upgrades+to+improve+our+services+to+you.+There+will+also+be+some+delays+to+online+publishing+between+25+to+28+September+2013.+We+apologize+for+the+inconvenience+and+appreciate+your+patience.+Thank+you+for+using+Wiley+Online+Library!

Comment: Sergiy, I've looked at the paper myself and I think that actually your conjecture implies a very simple (and strong) bound: $I(G) \leq n(n-1)$. Just plug $k=n$ into the Erdos-Gallai criterion. I've tried to find a counter-example to this but so far haven't - so it might even be true ;)

Comment: Felix, by $n$ you denote the number of edges in $G$? If so, then it is trivial bound.

Comment: Right! I got confused - what I should have written was $I(G) \leq m(m-1)$, where $m$ is the number of edges, which is indeed trivial (at least when the graph is connected). Sorry about that. Anyway, can I get in touch with you? I'm interested in the problem and would like to discuss it further.

Comment: Yes, of course! You can always mail me (kozerenkosergiy@ukr.net), for example :)